# Google play store internal testing can't install in Samsung S21 Ultra

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, mobile-development, google-play-internal-testing

I am publishing an app built with Flutter to play store for internal testing, but it appears a dialog show that the app can't be installed.

The problem happened in Samsung S21 Ultra

I am able to install it in Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.5

[image]

Comment: sounds phishi..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error few weeks ago. It appears that it occurs on Android devices with Android 12 installed.

I added this line in "android > app > build.gradle" with other implementations:

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```

Also, add this in activities using Intent in "android > app > src > AndroidManifest.xml":

```
android:exported="true"
```

Mine looks like this:

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop"
...
**android:exported="true"**>